# Mockito TooManyActualInvocations

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm using Junit and Mockito to test forward.
Here is part of `PortalServletTest` class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpTests() {
    when(request.getRequestDispatcher(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(rd);
    when(request.getSession()).thenReturn(httpSession);
    when(httpSession.getServletContext()).thenReturn(servletContext);
    when(servletContext.getAttribute(Constants.CONFIGURATION_MANAGER_ATTR)).thenReturn(configurationManager);
    when(configurationManager.getConfiguration()).thenReturn(configuration);
    List<List<String>> mandatoryHeaders = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    mandatoryHeaders.add(new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("HTTP_XXXX");
            add("http-xxxx");
        }
    });

    List<List<String>> optionalHeaders = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    optionalHeaders.add(new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("HTTP_YYYY");
            add("http-yyyy");
        }
    });

    when(configuration.getIdentificationHeaderFields()).thenReturn(mandatoryHeaders);
    when(configuration.getOptionalHeaderFields()).thenReturn(optionalHeaders);

}

@Test
public void testMissingHeadersRequest() throws IOException {
    when(request.getHeader(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null);
    target().path("/portal").request().get();
    Mockito.verify(response, times(1)).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_USE_PROXY, PortalServlet.MISSING_HEADERS_MSG);
}

@Test
public void testSuccesfulRequest() throws IOException, ServletException {
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
            String headerName = (String) args[0];
            return headerName;
        }
    }).when(request).getHeader(Mockito.anyString());
    target().path("/portal").request().get();
    verify(rd).forward(Mockito.any(ServletRequest.class), Mockito.any(ServletResponse.class));
}
```

The `PortalServlet` code:

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        rd.forward(mutableRequest, response);
```

The problem is that when testing the class, I'm getting the error message:

> requestDispatcher.forward(, );
>   Wanted 1 time:
>   -> at xxx.PortalServletTest.testSuccesfulRequest(PortalServletTest.java:140)
>
> But was 2 times. Undesired invocation:
>   -> at xxx.PortalServlet.addRequestHeaders(PortalServlet.java:144)
>
> at xxx.PortalServletTest.testSuccesfulRequest(PortalServletTest.java:140)

If I run each test individually they pass OK.
Looks like the forward from `PortalServlet` is count twice for each test.
Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show full code of PortalServletTest. I guess you initialize mock instance of PortalServlet only once for all tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to what @GhostCat wrote, I think you should [reset](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#17) all mocked objects before tests:

```
@Before
public void before() {
   Mockito.reset(/*mocked objects to reset*/)
   // mock them here or in individual tests
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,
I ended up adding Mockito.reset(response, rd) at the end of each tests.

    public void testMissingHeadersRequest() throws IOException {
  when(request.getHeader(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(null);
  target().path("/portal").request().get();
  Mockito.verify(response, times(1)).sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_USE_PROXY, PortalServlet.MISSING_HEADERS_MSG);
  Mockito.reset(response, rd);
 }

This solve the issue :)

Comment: Nice one ... missed that part ... plus one from me for that!

Answer (score 5):

You are using @BeforeClass to configure your mock objects.

That method is called **once** before your @Tests in your test class go executed.

You could simply try to change that to @Before!

In other words: before doing any tests, you configure your mocks to allow for **one** call. But then you are running multiple tests. If you assume that your mocks are all used the same way, you simply re-configure them **each time** for each @Test method.

Given your comment: does this

```
verify(rd, times(2)).forward ...
```

work/help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with @Before and getting the same error message. I also verified that the mock is configured before each test.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mockito BDD, then do it as below.

```
then(empRepository).should(times(3)).findById(emp.getId());
```